# JSONSerializer.toJSON ignores key 'class'

Tags: java, jsonserializer

How to convert JSON string to JSON by using JSONSerializer if the JSON string contains 'class' key? By using toJSON method all 'class' keys are ignored:

```java
String str = "{'test': 'ok', 'class' : 'fail'}";
JSON json = JSONSerializer.toJSON(str) // result is: {"test":"ok"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it:

```java
JsonConfig cfg = new JsonConfig();
cfg.setIgnoreDefaultExcludes(true);

JSON json = JSONSerializer.toJSON(str, cfg) // {"test":"ok", "class":"fail"}
```